# I can't compile my SDL project in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl

**The build log**

```
-------------- Build: Debug in SDLTEST (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\MingwLibs\SDL2-2.0.3\lib -o bin\Debug\SDLTEST.exe  obj\Debug\main.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

**My Code**

When I used hashtags it made the include bold.

```
(#)include <stdio.h>

(#)include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

**My Linker**

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Comment: if you use the code formatting tags, the code formatting will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your library search path is wrong. The standard distribution package of SDL2 contains two folders inside the lib folder, but you set the path directly to

> -LC:\MingwLibs\SDL2-2.0.3\lib

Try to use **C:\MingwLibs\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86** or **C:\MingwLibs\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x64** as your library path

Comment: I got this build error saying  `undefined reference to `WinMain@1`6

Comment: Looks like you are missing the WinMain function (this is a nonstandard entry point for Windows), but also according to the SDL docs you are missing the -mwindows flag. https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27WinMain.4016.27.22